# Text and Numbers Where Condition SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table (Number) where in one column have text and numbers feed.

and table have records like this

```
 NULL
 IGNORE
 domestic
 dead
 domestic 
 aggregated with 002
 shipperless
 Joint AQ
 tp
 IGNORE 
 1
 14
 0
 127207 AGG
 6
 20.56
 11.641
 537, 506
 21
 1,64,1395
 41727 kWh
 23
 25.9.2016 
 6
 36254
 36285
 36304
 36295
 36253
```

and my query is like this

```
select * from table
where number >= 10000 and number <100000
```

when i write the query its give me error of

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TPD' to data type int.
```

please any help me if any one understand the question

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Use try_convert(MONEY,youcol) if you want to capture values like 85,236 with or without the $,

Comment: This is a strange table. Is there no other column indicating what this column contains?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**TRY_CONVERT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql):

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,2),[number]) >= 10000
  AND TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,2),[number]) < 100000;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're expecting this to work to values such as `127207 AGG` and `41727 kWh` it won't (because the conversion will fail on account of the alpha characters at the end).

Comment: is this also adding which have 537, 506 ,41727 kWh and 1,64,1395

Comment: `537, 506 ,41727 kWh` would fail the `TRY_CONVERT` and not be included.

Comment: i need to add them

Comment: @Skorpian you're going to need to tell us what values you want to have returned then, as it's unclear. For example, how is 1,64,1396 >= 10,000 but <100,000? If we strip the non numeric characters it has, then it has a value of 1641396. That's more than 100000.

Comment: @Skorpion: but '41727 kWh' is not a number. And what number is `537, 506` supposed to represent? `537,506` maybe? And is a comma the decimal separator then or the thousand separator? And you would dismiss `1 km'`, but include `'10000 dm`', which is the same distance. Does that make sense? What is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @ Larnu there is the value under 100000 thats why i asked

Comment: so the value 1,64, 1396 is 3 different values? Well, we **can** catter for that, but then they have a value under 10000. So why do they need to display? For example, 64 is NOT greater than 10000. You are still unclear on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRY_PARSE` like this :

```
select * from table
where TRY_PARSE(number AS numeric(10,2)) between 10000 and 100000
```

Comment: is this also adding which have 537, 506 ,41727 kWh and 1,64,1395

Answer (score -1):

I can't post a comment, but if you only want to convert integers, try:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE TRY_CAST([number] AS INT) BETWEEN 10000 AND 100000
```

Comment: This may not quite get what the OP is after. They specifically state the value is < 100000. This solution would include values of 100000 and less than (but not including) 100001. That's because 100000.99999999999~ cast as a int is 100000 (which is BETWEEN 10000 and 100000).